# Setting an object's delegate multiple times

Tags: delegates

If I do object.delegate = self; then in that object's implementation do self.delegate = object;

Does that rewrite the object's delegate or does it assign it multiple delegates?

Comment: Not sure what is development language you are using, but looks like you reassign instead of adding like +=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do object.property = 1, then do object.property = 2, is property equal to both 1 and 2?

It'll rewrite the delegate.